Azure powershell Set-AzStorageLocalUser - how to use existing ssh key in azure?
I am trying to build powershell script to create a local user for sftp in the Azure Stroage account.
We have ssh keys already created in Azure. When the local user is created, existing ssh key created in azure should be assigned to the user. This can be easily done through Azure portal.

However, we are looking for the same option in the powershell commandlet.
Set-AzStorageLocalUser has option for "sshAuthorizedKey", but there is no option to select existing key.
Do we know how this can be achieved?

Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


Azure powershell Set-AzStorageLocalUser - how to use existing ssh key in azure?.

Unfortunately, there is not built PowerShell command that allows selecting an existing SSH key stored in Azure directly like you would in the portal.
However, you can fetch the public key and then use the Set-AzStorageLocalUser command to set it.
First, create ssh key in portal using this MS-Document.
Here is the script to set the Azure storage local user by fetch the public key and using in the command.
Script:
Connect-AzAccount

$resourceGroupName = "venkatesan-rg"
$storageAccountName = "venkat8912"
$localUserName = "venkat789"
$homeDirectory = "test"
$sshKeyName="venkat123"

$sshKey = Get-AzSshKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $sshKeyName }
$publicKey = $sshKey.PublicKey

$sshPublicKey = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.Models.PSSshPublicKey
$sshPublicKey.Key = $publickey

$permissionScope = New-AzStorageLocalUserPermissionScope -Permission rw -Service blob -ResourceName $homeDirectory

Set-AzStorageLocalUser -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -Name $localUserName -HomeDirectory $homeDirectory -SshAuthorizedKey $sshPublicKey -PermissionScope $permissionScope

Output:

   ResourceGroupName: venkatesan-xxx, StorageAccountName: venkatxxxx

Name      Sid                                          HomeDirectory HasSharedKey HasSshKey HasSshPassword PermissionScopes
----      ---                                          ------------- ------------ --------- -------------- ----------------
venkatxxx S-1-2-0-18xxx16111-3xxxx77448-110771702-1002 test                                                [test]          


Portal:

